# Typescript misidentifies express application type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

It's my first attempt to set up node with typescript, following a tutorial. The code below leads to the wrong suggestion for the `app.listen` function (see image).

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.listen(3000)
```

[image]

The first argument supposed to be a port. And while I'm still typing the function name, this is reflected in the suggesstion:

[image]

Specifying the `app` type as `express.Application` does not help.

I have installed `@types/express`, `@types/node`, `ts-node` and `typescript` as dev dependencies. In `tsconfig.js`, I have the following settings: `{ "target": "es6", "module": "commonjs", "moduleResolution": "node" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listen()` method has 6 overloads as can be seen in your image. The overload  with 1 argument is displayed first as it is the shortest one. If you type a number and a `,` inside the function, you will see the discription change to what you are expecting.

The overloads are defined as follows:

```
listen(port: number, hostname: string, backlog: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
listen(port: number, hostname: string, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
listen(port: number, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
listen(callback?: () => void): http.Server;
listen(path: string, callback?: () => void): http.Server;
listen(handle: any, listeningListener?: () => void): http.Server;
```

VSC shows the hint which is as close to what you are typing as possible. Since you didn't supply any argument, the closest signature is the one with only the callback.